# Javascript array manipulation

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to create string (delimited by pipe '||') from the contents of an array. I want to remover $ from the item and add || between two items. But I don't want to add || after the last array item. Easiest way to do this?

This is what I have done so far:

```
var array = ["$db1", "$db2", "$db3", "$db4"];

var dbs = "";

for(var i = 0; i < array.length, i++){
    if(array[i].charAt(0) == "$"){
        dbs += array[i].replace("$","") + "||";
        alert(dbs);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go:

```
array.join('||').replace(/\$/g,'')
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZrgFV/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Can you explain the pattern for replace?

Comment: @JSRookie [Read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). In short, `/\$/g` is a regular expression which matches all `$` characters in the string. The second argument is an empty string (`''`) which means that all `$` characters are replaced by an empty string (= they are deleted from the string).

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = ["$db1", "$db2", "$db3", "$db4"];
var arrStr = array.join("||");
var dbs = arrStr.replace(/\$/g, "");
```

Grr sorry forgot to add the \g switch to replace all.

Comment: This fails miserably with more than one item. Did you actually test it? `.replace` with a string only replaces the first occurrence of the string.

Comment: without a global regex your last line will only replace the first $

Comment: Yea i saw that and not it's fixed

Comment: *Now* it does. Notifying @tomfumb?

Answer (score 0):

```
var array = ["$db1", "$db2", "$db3", "$db4"];
var dbs = array.map(function(x) { return x.substring(1); }).join('||');
```

It requires the relatively new `Array.map`, so also include:

```
if(![].map) Array.prototype.map = function(f) {
    var r = [], i = 0;
    for(; i < this.length; i++) r.push(f(this[i]));
    return r;
};
```

I took it that you meant "remove a leading $" because they're all at the beginning. If not, use:

```
var array = ["$db1", "$db2", "$db3", "$db4"];
var dbs = array.join('||').replace(/\$/g, '');
```

Comment: Your Array.prototype.map won't do anything but copy the array, I think you meant to `r.push(f(this[i]))`

Answer (score 0):

```
array.join('||').replace(/(^|(\|\|))\$/g, '$1');
```

Join with `||`, then annihilate any `$` following either the beginning of the string or the separator. Works as long as your strings do not contain `||` (in which case, I think you have bigger problems).

Answer (score -2):

```
var dbs = array.join('||').replace(/$/gi, '');
```

This.

Comment: case-insensitive seems a little redundant here!

Comment: `$` is a special regex character and  `i` is unnecessary.